# How to reimplement lsof +D on MacOS two avoid calling stat(2) twice?

Tags: python, macos, file-descriptor, lsof

I am using [lsof](https://ss64.com/osx/lsof.html) to detect which files are opened by which process for a given directory. Example:

```
% lsof +D /Users/jack/Downloads
Spotify 1431 jack   75r   DIR    1,6      128 37333 /Users/jack/Downloads/file1.png
Dock    1439 jack   13r   DIR    1,6      128 37333 /Users/jack/Downloads/foo.psd
zsh     6644 jack  cwd    DIR    1,6      128 37333 /Users/jack/Downloads/foo.bmp
```

The man page of `lsof(8)` states:

> lsof may process this option slowly and require a
> large amount of dynamic memory to do it.  This is because it must
> descend the entire directory tree, rooted at D, **calling stat(2) for
> each file and directory**, building a list of all the files it finds,
> and searching that list for a match with every open file.  When
> directory D is large, these steps can take a long time, so use this
> option prudently.

Coincidentally I am already traversing the directory and call [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) inside Python right before I call `lsof`, means `stat(2)` is technically called twice.

Which information does does the stat object hold that I could process myself to imitate the functionality of `lsof`? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what your python program is doing, and why and how it calls lsof ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find open files by process using the `/proc` filesystem. From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> /proc/[pid]/fd/
> This is a subdirectory containing one entry for each file
> which the process has open, named by its file descriptor,
> and which is a symbolic link to the actual file.  Thus, 0
> is standard input, 1 standard output, 2 standard error,
> and so on.
> For file descriptors for pipes and sockets, the entries
> will be symbolic links whose content is the file type with
> the inode.  A readlink(2) call on this file returns a
> string in the format: type:[inode]

Here is a small example script that lists all open files per process.

```py
import os

def find_open_files(pid, prefix="/"):
    fds = os.listdir(f"/proc/{pid}/fd")
    open_files = []
    for fd in fds:
        try:
            # read the symlink from the file descrptior files
            open_file = os.readlink(f"/proc/{pid}/fd/{fd}")
            # this is a simple filter to only show "real" files
            # as stated in the manpage open_file could be something like socket:[1234]
            if open_file.startswith(prefix):
                open_files.append(open_file)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # These errors happen, if
            #  1. the process exits in the time between our listdir and the readlink
            #  2. the file is closed before we reach readlink
            pass
    return open_files


proc_files = os.listdir("/proc")
# find all numeric dirs as there are also other dirs in /proc present
pids = [p for p in proc_files if p.isnumeric()]
all_open_files = {}
for pid in pids:
    all_open_files[pid] = find_open_files(pid)

print(all_open_files)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately MacOS doesn't have a `/proc/` directory.